# MY_Controller extend cant show data ( Codeigniter )

Tags: codeigniter

I have changed my application core/MY_Controller.php extendable. Before I could get data from mysql but Now I get Message: Undefined variable: records. How can i get data again ? 
MY_Controller.php :

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

  protected $data = array();

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  function render_page($view) {
    //do this to don't repeat in all controllers...
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
    //menu_data must contain the structure of the menu...
    //you can populate it from database or helper

    $this->load->view($view, $this->data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $this->data);
  }
```

My home controller :

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {
         function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
public function view($page = 'home')
    {
     $this->load->helper('text');
        $this->data['records']= $this->services_model->getAll();
        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter


        $this->render_page('pages/'.$page,$this->data);


    }
```

Services_model :

```
class Services_model extends CI_Model {


    function getAll() {
        $q = $this->db->get('services');
        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach ($q->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;

            }
        return $data;
    }
    }
```

This is the where i get error in home.php view :

```
<ul class="blog-medium">
<?php foreach($records->result() as $row): ?>
    <li><h1><a href="./post.html"><?php echo $row->title; ?></a></h1></li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The error message shows : Message: Undefined variable: records

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. Is this really your code? What is this: `$data['records']= $this-class Home extends MY_Controller {`?? And this: `function __construct() {>services_model->getAll();`? Please fix the question and post your actual code.

Comment: Mischa , It is a copy/paste error. I have realized now . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your controller it looks like you are setting `$data['records']` when you should be setting `$this->data['records']`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. In my Home controller, I was using the view as :

```
$this->render_page('pages/'.$page,$this->data);
```

But I have to use it as here :

```
class Home extends MY_Controller {
         function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

        public function view($page = 'home')
        {
         $this->load->helper('text');
            $this->data['records']= $this->services_model->getAll();
            if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter


            $this->render_page('pages/'.$page,$data);


        }
```

I dont know why but I tried this before. It did not make but it is working now.